# What is the solution for “Labels in tree and data differ” and “object of type 'closure' is not subsettable” Errors in modelTest”?

Tags: r, syntax

I’m trying to get the evolutionary model for my translated DNA to Protein file by phangorn and ape tools. With the codes I've already used now I have Errors! I tried to change .fasta file format to .phy or .nex., installing the other versions of R (4.1.1, 4.1.2) and finally trying whatever the codes we have for modeltest in tutorials but they didn’t work out! My question is that why there would be difference between labels as the tree is created form the given file. For the second error, I didn’t square bracket but it count it as subtitled!

```
library(ape)

library(phangorn)

file="C:/Users/ItCenter/Desktop/n.fasta"

Dat=read.phyDat(file,format="fasta",type="AA")

mt = modelTest(Dat, tree = NULL, model = c ("WAG ", "JTT", "LG", "Dayhoff ", "cpREV", "mtmam", "mtArt", "MtZoa", "mtREV24", "VT", "RtREV", "HIVw", "HIVb", "FLU", "Blosum62", "Dayhoff_DCMut", "JTT_DCMut"), G = TRUE, I = TRUE, FREQ = FALSE, k = 4, control = pml.control(epsilon = 1e-08, maxit = 10, trace = 1), multicore = FALSE, mc.cores = NULL)
```

> Error in modelTest(Dat, model = c("WAG", "JTT", "LG", "Dayhoff",
> "cpREV",  :   Labels in tree and data differ!

```
modelTest(Dat,phyDat,NULL)
```

> Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: In R, a "closure" is a function with its defining environment (i.e., every function is a closure). It's never good to guess, but your question is incomplete, but ... if your references to `modelTest` and `phyDat` are from package `phangorn`, then the second argument `tree=` is expecting *data*, not a function as in your last call.

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in `modelTest`, which I seem to have introduced recently, if one did not supply a tree. It is fixed now in the development version now. Best you download this version:

```
remotes::install_github("KlausVigo/phangorn")
```

and than

```
modelTest(Dat)
```

should work. Or you compute a tree beforehand, e.g.

```
tree <- NJ(dist.ml(chloroplast, "LG")) 
modelTest(Dat, tree)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Downloading new version of phangorn didn't work out. But as you said computing a tree worke out.